# Create street map with A-10 type grid & index

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to create a printed map using QGIS with an arbitrary grid superimposed, such as is usually found on street maps.. say A to K on one axis and 1 to 10 on the other. Then I will need to create an index showing how to find each street.

[image]

I don't know how to do either part of this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a plugin called **[Create Indexed Vector Grid](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/createnamedgrid/)**

(disclosure: I'm the author of the plugin)

It creates a regular grid of named cells, and each cell can be named using a spreadsheet-like naming convention.

It works best if you use a CRS in meters (assuming you're covering a city).

You can use a spatial join (Join Attributes by Location) to find out which cell each features falls into, and use Map Composer Attribute Tables to make an index, as in the London A-Z or a typical road atlas.

There's a [blog post about it here](http://www.stevefaeembra.com/blog/2015/10/8/road-atlas-style-grids-in-qgis), and an [example here on flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stevefaeembra/17029421129)